# How to remove previous unix domain socket while closing RTCpeerconnection in webrtc in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, webrtc, video-streaming, rtcpeerconnection

```
const { RTCPeerConnection } = require('wrtc')


this.peerConnection =  new RTCPeerConnection(this.rtcConfig)
```

------------- some coding --------------------------------------------------

```
this.peerConnection.close();
```

//In above code i am closing the peerConnection but still previous unix domain socket continue to //exist and not getting destroyed and its increasing whenever i create new peer connection- below are //the logs of my process checked in terminal

```
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3410597  14738/Liveview       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3417284  14738/Liveview       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3417285  14738/Liveview       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3410598  14738/Liveview       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3405499  14738/Liveview       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3410595  14738/Liveview       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3405497  14738/Liveview       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3410594  14738/Liveview
```

i am expecting that when we close the rtcpeerconnection the unix domain socket related to that peer connection should be cleared